# List all routes in Vapor

Tags: swift, routes, vapor

I want to inspect a list of all routes, that Vapor app is serving. Is there a script or a run-time command that will generate the list for me?

I'm looking for something similar to `rake routes` in Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `vapor run routes` from the command line after executing `vapor build`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to get the routes use the following command. It will build your project and displays all routes registered to the `Application`'s `Router` in an ASCII-formatted table.

```
 $ swift run Run routes

 +------+------------------+
 | GET  | /search          |
 +------+------------------+
 | GET  | /hash/:string    |
 +------+------------------+
```

A colon preceding a path component indicates a variable parameter. A colon with no text following is a parameter whose result will be discarded.